# Documentation for a tightly secured IIS7.5 web server

Tags: iis-7.5

I am looking for a published doc which details recommendations to configure a tightly secured IIS7.5 web server...

Env:
- Microsoft Server 2008 R2
- IIS7.5
- Intranet facing

Answer (score 0):

[NSA STIGS](http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/stig/) are always good: http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/downloads/zip/unclassified_web_server_v7r1_stig.zip